# Problems with ggplot when use markdown to PDF

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, r-markdown, themes

I have a plot that seems doesn't have any problem when I run it in the console of Rstudio, but when I try to get a PDF output with Rmarkdown, the code rise an error:

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = cyl)) + geom_line() +
  hrbrthemes::theme_modern_rc() +
  labs(title = "Plot")
```

[image]

Here's the error:

Error in grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, : invalid font type Calls: ...
drawDetails -> drwDetails.text -> grid.Call.graphics Además: There were 50 warnings (use warningswarnings() to see the firs 50) Ejecución interrumpida

In grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
font family not found in Windows font database

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It helps SEO and will help other readers if you include the actual error in text, not an image: images break SEO and screen-readers. Please [edit] your question and add the text itself (typically in a code block). Thanks.

Comment: Try adding `dev = "cairo_pdf"` to chunk options.

Comment: @r2evans in the console didn't appear the error, but anyway I write it.

Comment: @henrik_ibsen Thanks a lot, that was the solution

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add dev = "cairo_pdf" to chunk options as henrik_ibsen said